# Xslt Syntax highlighting for c xsl-fo

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have this codeblock for xst-fo

```
  <codeblock outputclass="language-c"><![CDATA[
   #define VALUE1 100 /* Comment */
   #define VALUE2 200 /* Comment */
   #define VALUE3 300 /* Comment */
   #define VALUE4 400 /* Comment */]]></codeblock>
```

But when the pdf is generated I get this output:
[image: Pdf Output]

Only the first comment in the #define list is good. The rest is not highlighted.
What is wrong with this?

Comment: Neither the W3C standard XSLT nor the XSL-FO standard define any `codeblock` element I think so you seem to be using XSLT to process some not shown input format to a particular output format where you expect it to later ensure some color coding in the PDF output. Unless you share which target or intermediary format you are trying to us and how you transform it I am not sure anyone can help.

Comment: Are your using DITA with DITA Open Toolkit? If so, what plug-in are you using?

Comment: I'm using dita-ot and [Syntax Highlighter](https://sourceforge.net/p/xslthl/wiki/Syntax%20Highlighters/) plugin.
But it seems that the highlighter is taking the '#' as directive and ignore whatever follows it, that's why the comment is not working.\